# Measuring xcodebuild durations for all targets (including dependent ones)

Tags: xcode, profiling, xcodebuild

Is it possible to measure time, that single `xcodebuild` command consumes to build every distinct target?

Let's say I have a target, which depends on some `cocoapod`s: `pod1` and `pod2`.
I build my target using `xcodebuild`. I can measure overall time.
I need to measure times, that were separately spent on `pod1`, `pod2` and my target

I tried to find the answer in `xcodebuild`'s output, but failed to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I ended up writing a custom `ruby` script for modifing every target of my `xcodeproj` and of `Pods.xcodeproj`. This script adds two `build phase`s that log the target name and current timestamp into an output file. One `build phase` executes first, an the other one executes last. Later on I simply substract one timestamp from another in a separate script.

Here is the result of the script:

[image: /Users/tryusipov/Desktop/screenshots/Image 2017-11-17 18-23-49.png]

---

The output file will look like this (after sorting)

```
Alamofire end: 1510929112.3409
Alamofire start: 1510929110.2161
AlamofireImage end: 1510929113.6925
AlamofireImage start: 1510929112.5205
```

Path to the output file (`/a/ci_automation/metrics/performance-metrics/a.txt` on the screenshot) is not hardcoded anyhow. Instead, you pass it as a parameter of a `ruby` script like this:

`$ruby prepare-for-target-build-time-profiling.rb ${PWD}/output.txt`

Note, that this script requires `cocoapods 1.3.1` (maybe `1.3`).

---

Here is the `ruby` script: `ruby prepare-for-target-build-time-profiling.rb`

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'xcodeproj'
require 'cocoapods'
require 'fileutils'

def inject_build_time_profiling_build_phases(project_path)
    project = Xcodeproj::Project.open(project_path)

    log_time_before_build_phase_name = '[Prefix placeholder] Log time before build'.freeze
    log_time_after_build_phase_name = '[Prefix placeholder] Log time after build'.freeze

    puts "Patching project at path: #{project_path}"
    puts
    project.targets.each do |target|
        puts "Target: #{target.name}"

        first_build_phase = create_leading_build_phase(target, log_time_before_build_phase_name)
        last_build_phase = create_trailing_build_phase(target, log_time_after_build_phase_name)

        puts
    end

    project.save

    puts "Finished patching project at path: #{project_path}"
    puts
end

def create_leading_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)
    remove_existing_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)

    build_phase = create_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)

    shift_build_phase_leftwards(target, build_phase)

    is_build_phase_leading = true

    inject_shell_code_into_build_phase(target, build_phase, is_build_phase_leading)

    return build_phase
end

def create_trailing_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)
    remove_existing_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)

    build_phase = create_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)

    is_build_phase_leading = false

    inject_shell_code_into_build_phase(target, build_phase, is_build_phase_leading)

    return build_phase
end

def remove_existing_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)
    existing_build_phase = target.shell_script_build_phases.find do |build_phase|
        build_phase.name.end_with?(build_phase_name)
        # We use `end_with` instead of `==`, because `cocoapods` adds its `[CP]` prefix to a `build_phase_name`
    end

    if !existing_build_phase.nil?
        puts "deleting build phase #{existing_build_phase.name}"

        target.build_phases.delete(existing_build_phase)
    end
end

def create_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)
    puts "creating build phase: #{build_phase_name}"

    build_phase = Pod::Installer::UserProjectIntegrator::TargetIntegrator
        .create_or_update_shell_script_build_phase(target, build_phase_name)

    return build_phase
end

def shift_build_phase_leftwards(target, build_phase)
    puts "moving build phase leftwards: #{build_phase.name}"

    target.build_phases.unshift(build_phase).uniq! unless target.build_phases.first == build_phase
end

def inject_shell_code_into_build_phase(target, build_phase, is_build_phase_leading)
    start_or_end = is_build_phase_leading ? "start" : "end"

    build_phase.shell_script = <<-SH.strip_heredoc
        timestamp=`echo "scale=4; $(gdate +%s%N/1000000000)" | bc`
        echo "#{target.name} #{start_or_end}: ${timestamp}" >> #{$build_time_logs_output_file}
    SH
end

def parse_arguments
    $build_time_logs_output_file = ARGV[0]

    if $build_time_logs_output_file.to_s.empty? || ! $build_time_logs_output_file.start_with?("/")
        puts "Error: you should pass a full path to a output file as an script's argument. Example:"
        puts "$ruby prepare-for-target-build-time-profiling.rb /path/to/script/output.txt"
        puts
        exit 1
    end
end

def print_arguments
    puts "Arguments:"
    puts "Output path: #{$build_time_logs_output_file}"
    puts
end

def clean_up_before_script
    if File.exist?($build_time_logs_output_file)
        FileUtils.rm($build_time_logs_output_file)
    end

    build_time_logs_output_folder = File.dirname($build_time_logs_output_file)
    unless File.directory?(build_time_logs_output_folder)
        FileUtils.mkdir_p(build_time_logs_output_folder)
    end
end

def main 
    parse_arguments
    print_arguments
    clean_up_before_script
    inject_build_time_profiling_build_phases("path/to/project.xcodeproj")
    inject_build_time_profiling_build_phases("path/to/pods/project.xcodeproj")
end

# arguments:
$build_time_logs_output_file

main
```

Comment: For macOS users who had issues with this script, gdate is part of the GNU CoreUtils, typically used on Linux. macOS uses BSD CoreUtils, which prefers date over gdate. This script will silently break if you use gdate, or if you change the script to use gdate. 

To fix: Install GNU CoreUtils (brew install coreutils)

Comment: Also there is an another interesting private xcode flag which will output the build trace if you use it: `XCEmitTimeTrace="YES" xcodebuild .....`